# Failing to copy set of integers in main function to a dynamically allocated memory in copy() function

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic

Below is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int *glob_var;
int* copy(void *a,int size)
{
    int *t=(int *)calloc(1,sizeof(int));
    int i;
    int *glob_var=(int *)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
    printf("glob_var=%p\n",glob_var);
    printf("a=%p\n",a);
    t=glob_var;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        *glob_var=*(int *)a;
         glob_var++;

         (int *)a++;
        // printf("a=%p\n",a);

    }
    glob_var=t;
     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       printf("%d\t",*glob_var);
       glob_var++;

    }
glob_var=t;
printf("\n%p\n",glob_var);
return t;
}
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    int a=0x123456,i;
    int *var=(int *)calloc(10,sizeof(int));
    int *temp;
    temp=var;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        *var=i;
        var++;

    }
    var=temp;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       printf("%d\n",*var);
        var++;


    }
    var=temp;
    printf("var=%p\n",var);

    glob_var=copy(var,10);
    printf("%p\n",glob_var);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       printf("%d\t",*glob_var);
       glob_var++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the output I got is :

```
0       16777216        65536   256     1       33554432        131072  512     2       50331648
```

I was expecting:  `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

But, in the `copy()` function, if I replace `(int *)a++;` with `a=(int *)a+1;` it is working.

My question is: What is wrong with the current program?

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic on a pointer-to-void (`void*`) is not allowed in C<sup>1</sup> and your compiler should warn you about that (at the very least) in the following line:

```c
(int *)a++;
```

When I compile your code (using the clang-cl compiler in Visual Studio), I do, indeed, get *two* warnings for that line:

> warning : arithmetic on a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-Wpointer-arith]
> warning : expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

The first of these addresses the issue mentioned in my opening line (and discussed in the footnote) but it is the second that should be ringing alarm bells. That shows that the cast isn't working as intended – it is actually applied to the *result* of the `a++` operation, because [the cast has lower precedence than the post-increment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

However, when you use `a = (int *)a + 1;`, then all is working as intended, because the `a` pointer is cast to an `int*` **before** the arithmetic is performed (and then implicitly cast back to a `void*` for the assignment).

(There are other issues in your code, like the re-declaration of `glob_var` in your function, and the use of non-void pointers as arguments for the `%p` format specifier in several `printf` calls – but these are not really related to your reported problem. Also, this is worth a read: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073))

---

<sup>1</sup> Some C compilers, such as GCC, do allow arithmetic on `void*` pointers, but I do not know what the 'base unit size' is for such operations. One would have to read the GCC manual to determine that, but it may very well by just `1`, rather than the `sizeof(int)` required for your program, as presented, to work. Indeed, if that assumption is correct, and `sizeof(int)` is `4` on your platform, it would explain the three "garbage values" between successive 'real' data in your output.